# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when creating virtualenv

Tags: python, logging, module, virtualenv

I wanted to create a virtualenv for python 2.7 (I'm using 3.7)

I run the cmd as admin (on windows 10) :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>virtualenv -p C:\Python27\python.exe py27
```

An I got the error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Python27\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path\to\virtualenv.py", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import threading
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 15, in <module>
    from collections import deque
  File "C:\Python27\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 55
    raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}')
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I Launch Python2.7 and try to import the logging module: It show the same error but When I retype it. It work just fine:

```
>>> import logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import threading
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 15, in <module>
    from collections import deque
  File "C:\Python27\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 55
    raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}')
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import logging
>>> logging.warning('hello word')
WARNING:root:hello word
>>>
```

I can't figure out why it does that.

I have already configured a virtual env with python 3.6

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you once check the package for python 2.7 which you have downloaded matches with your system config (32 Bit or 64 Bit)?

Comment: Second: Possibly you do not have `logging` module installed in your 2.7 virtual env. try installing it with `pip install logging` in that virtual env

Comment: I reinstalled python 2.7 in 64 Bit, I still have the same error. I do not have the python 2.7 in environnement var, thus the logging module **is installed** I managed  to get a `logging.warning('hello word')
WARNING:root:hello word` but only at the second try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a version problem. This line

```
raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}')
```

is being run under Python 2.7, but is Python 3.6 (or 3.7) and will give you a syntax error in earlier versions. In your case I would treat that Python 2.7 installation as irretrievably broken, because it is clear that the standard library isn't to be trusted to all be of a consistent version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved deleting the c:\Python27 directory, Then Uninstalling python 2.7 using the setup tool, restarting the computer and reinstalling Python 2.7