# virtualenv --help gives the following error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

If I run `virtualenv --help`, it prints out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .plugin.activators import ActivationSelector
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv/run/plugin/activators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import ComponentBuilder
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv/run/plugin/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from importlib_metadata import entry_points
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 88
    dist: Optional['Distribution'] = None
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My default python3 version is python 3.9.

If instead I run `python3 -m venv .`, it prints out only the following single-line error:

```
Error: Command '['/media/ubuntu/600GBVolume/freetutorials/enviorn/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: virtualenv seems to be using 3.5 not 3.9?

Comment: cant be similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56424857/3157428)?

Comment: And Python 3.5 does not yet support the type annotation in the code.