# python3 -m venv new-env returned as invalid syntax

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm currently working on a new python project using VS Code, through a forked repository on GitHub.
However, when i tried to create a new virtual environment, invalid syntax was returned. Anyone knows why is this so?

Python version installed: Python 3.9.6

```
>>> python3 -m venv new-env
  File "<stdin>", line 1   
    python3 -m venv new-env
               ^
```

Comment: did you install virtualenv?

Comment: ----------
This might help [SyntaxError: invalid syntax when creating virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424857/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-when-creating-virtualenv) ----------

Answer (score 0):

> python3 -m venv new-env

I think you are trying to run this command in the [python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) and the python interpreter is intended to run python snippets only.

`python3 -m venv new-env` is supposed to be run on [cmdline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface).

Run `python3 -m venv new-env` inside the CLI ([cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) for windows, [shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87853/what-is-default-shell-for-terminal#:%7E:text=GNU%20Bash%20is%20the%20shell,echo%20%24SHELL%20in%20the%20terminal.) for Linux)it will work fine.

If you want to learn more about this kind of topics you can refer to the free GitHub learning program available [here](https://lab.github.com/)

Comment: Thanks Prakash. I ran it inside the terminal, have yet to select the python interpreter. I missed out installing virtualenv. managed to create the new environment after that.